# Format number to separate thousand values (eg 12000000 would become 12 000 000)

Tags: lua, numbers, currency

In lua, I would like to format an integer (or float) number to separate every three decimal places with a space (or a coma, as in US), so for example number 120000010 would be presented as
120 000 010
or
120,000,010

I have found [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers), but is there a way to achieve this using string.format, or any other way not involving custom implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` (and friends) can do it with the (according to the man page) `SUSv2` format flag `'`.

So `printf "%'d\n" 1000000` outputs `1,000,000` but lua doesn't seem to support passing that through to the system `printf` calls.

To clarify this answer for whoever down-voted me. The answer here is "No". The only way to use `string.format` for this would be to use that flag which, as indicated, lua does not pass through. As such there is no way, that I'm aware of, to do this without a custom solution such as that linked in the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but as you say - it doesn't seem to work for lua.

Comment: lua limits the flags that can be passed through to the system. I believe to increase portability and to prevent unexpected crashes from non-conforming system libraries.

Comment: I was unaware of the `%'d` flag.