# Formatting numbers with shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have this Script:

```
var=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
echo "$(($var / 1024)) MB / 12.288 MB Memory free\n"
```

it outputs something like this:

```
10887 MB / 12.288 MB Memory free
```

But for better readability I want the first number to be like this `10.887` I tried [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html), but for some reasons it's not included in my destro or coreutils.

EDIT: because of some misconceptions: this is european formatting so we separate with "." and decimal digits are initiated with ","

Comment: Also that entire first pipeline can be reduced to `sed -ne '/MemFree/{s/[^0-9]//g;p}' /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25726171/258523). (Ignore the lua bits the `printf` bit is the important part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your code with `awk`:

```
awk '/MemTotal/{m=$2/(1024*1024)}
     /MemFree/{printf "%.3f GB / %.3f GB Memory free\n", $2/(1024*1024), m}' /proc/meminfo
1.721 GB / 3.675 GB Memory free
```

Comment: mhh in my case it outputs 10905.410 MB so it adds 3 digits ;D But I want to group like 1.000.000

Comment: Ahh I know, I made it a bit unclear, where I live, we don't seperate numbers with commas, we use points. you would say 1.23 kg (= 1230 g) we say 1,23 kg :)

Comment: So what's your actual expected output?

Comment: Here's trying to separate positional units in a whole number. Not indicate fractional units of a number.

Comment: May be I am slow to understand but I still want to know what is exact output OP is expecting. Also don't understand intent of hardcoded `/ 12.288 MB Memory free` in question.

Comment: i guess 10,887 MB / 12,288 MB would be how you would write it. converted to Gb this would be ~10 GB / ~12 GB.
Because the second amount doesn't change. there are only 12 gigs in the system.

Comment: after your edit, it worked for me, nice! thank you! :)

Comment: And I edited further to get total physical memory also from same `/proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` (and friends) can do it with the (according to the man page) `SUSv2` format flag `'`.

So this should do what you want if your locale is set correctly.

```
memfree=$(sed -ne '/MemFree/{s/[^0-9]//g;p}' /proc/meminfo)
printf "%'d MB / 12.288 MB Memory free\n" "$((memfree / 1024))"
```